# Javascript - .replace method not removing whitespace

Tags: javascript, string

I'm attempting to use the `.replace` method to alter my strings of text to remove any special characters, and to replace the white space with a `-`

For example:

I'd like to alter `"Breakfast & Lunch & Dinner "` to `Breakfast-Lunch-Dinner`

I do not want to replace special characters with the `-` so to speak, but i'd like to replace the white spaces available with `-`

So for example, if I have another text using the same `.replace` method such as `"Football Basketball Rugby"` to return `Football-Basketball-Rugby`

At the moment I my string is returning with an `-` but also including the whitespace in between.

Here is a code snippet of my code:

```js
string = 'Breakfast & Lunch & Dinner'

secondString = 'Football Basketball Rugby'


newString = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]\s/g, '-');


newSecondString = secondString.replace(/\s+/g, '-')


console.log(newString)

console.log(newSecondString)
```

Comment: What about more than one space? `'  ' -> '--'`?

Comment: "At the moment I my string is returning with an - but also including the whitespace in between." — no, it isn't.

Comment: I would like it to return only one `-` and not a `--`

Comment: Why do you have a `\s` after your negated character class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```js
string = 'Breakfast & Lunch & Dinner'
newString = string.replace(/([^a-zA-Z0-9]*|\s*)\s/g, '-');
console.log(newString)
```

Answer (score 1):

just add a + to the array; it already implies \s and can be used for both

```
newString = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '-');
```

```js
string = 'Breakfast & Lunch & Dinner'

secondString = 'Football Basketball Rugby'


newString = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '-');


newSecondString = secondString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '-')


console.log(newString)

console.log(newSecondString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
string = 'Breakfast & Lunch & Dinner'




newString = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]\s/g, '-').replace(/ /g,'');





console.log(newString)
```